# cannot install new drivers for ATI Radeon HD mobility

Tags: drivers, integrated-graphics

I have an ATI mobility Radeon HD 3200 graphics card  with a driver that I downloaded from my computer manufacturer's site. I wanted to upgrade the driver so I downloaded the respective driver from ATI and ran the installation. However, the installation only installs the download manager, the App SDK, C++ distributables and CCC, no display driver. When I try opening the CCC, I get an error that quits the CCC, something about the display driver not being recognized.

What is wrong here? How do I go about fixing this?

thanks

Comment: Give a link to the page you downloaded from.

Comment: @BenVoigt http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx i used the auto detect, the other option gave me the verification tool only

Comment: also, what OS??  The verification tool is what you want, though, if it detects a compatible Radeon it will start the download of the main driver.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm on win7 64bit, and I also tried the veri tool, same results

Comment: Hmm, just wanted to make sure you were getting the Mobility package and not the desktop one.  The verifier thing works for me, but I have a Mobility 5650.  The latest drivers might no longer work with the 3xxx series.

Comment: Have you tried the free [SlimDrivers](http://www.driverupdate.net/) tool?